# Error "Failed to OpenForBackup failed in Win32" when pulling microsoft/nanoserver container

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I encounter the following error when attempting to pull the microsoft/nanoserver image.  The download is successful. This error occurs during extraction of the image.

> 482ab31872a2: Download complete
>   failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: **Failed to OpenForBackup failed in Win32**: open \?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\07bd46b89b4520e984bc0892bad2c955afec4b347f961ca6c31bfe5e30601806\Files\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts: **Access is denied.** (0x1f) \?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\07bd46b89b4520e984bc0892bad2c955afec4b347f961ca6c31bfe5e30601806\Files\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

This looks like a issue on the directory that the Windows image creates, but I can't figure out what permission the directory may need.

Here is my Docker version (Windows Containers):

**Docker version**

Client:

```
 Version:      1.13.0-rc2**

 API version:  1.25

 Go version:   go1.7.3

 Git commit:   1f9b3ef

 Built:        Wed Nov 23 17:40:58 2016

 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
```

**Server:

```
 Version:             1.13.0-rc2**

 API version:         1.25

 Minimum API version: 1.24

 Go version:          go1.7.3

 Git commit:          1f9b3ef

 Built:               Wed Nov 23 17:40:58 2016

 OS/Arch:             windows/amd64

 Experimental:        false
```

Here is the Docker command I am using to pull the image.

```
docker pull microsoft/nanoserver
```

Finally, here is the error message that after the image is downloaded and extracted:

> This is a Windows 10 Professional workstation with build 14393 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this problem was that a virus scan policy (MacAfee) was preventing access to the Windows image's host file.  The policy was relaxed so that the host.dll process could have access to the directory.  Once updated I had no problems pulling the nanonserver or aspnet images.

Comment: can you please elaborate the solution

Comment: Same problem with me. After disable McAfee McShield the problem disappear.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error but `The file exists` instead of `Access is denied`.

My problem was that I had it in Windows containers mode.

Switching back to Linux fixed it for me.

Comment: You can found how to switch back to Linux here:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers