# Dockerfile to build an image for executable file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Am new to Docker Technology and am trying to build and image and container for an .exe file.

My team has build an exe file in visual studio on Windows, to run a job. And now i need to write a dockerfile to create an image and container. so that when ever i start my container the job has to run.

This is what my dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
MAINTAINER me@gmail.com
COPY . /app/
CMD ["/app/Controller.exe", "run"]
```

I have switch my docker to Windows container. And when i try to build an image using this docker file am getting below error.
[image]

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47615434/edit) paste the contents of the image as text, indented by for spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is usually related to strong antivirus policies. See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997051/error-failed-to-openforbackup-failed-in-win32-when-pulling-microsoft-nanoserve) and [this post](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/292). If you have the ability to, try disabling your antivirus completely and rebuilding. If it works, you'll need to identify which policy is obstructing access to `C:\ProgramData\Docker` and add an exclusion.